# Is there a way to search fhir resources on a text search parameter using wildcards?

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to search for all Observations where "blood" is associated with the code using:

```
GET [base]/Observation?code:text=blood
```

It appears that the search is matching Observations where the associated text starts with "blood" but not matching on associated text that contains "blood".

Using the following, I get results with a Coding.display of "Systolic blood pressure" but I'd like to also get these Observations by searching using the text "blood".

```
GET [base]/Observation?code:text=sys
```

Is there a different modifier I should be using or wildcards I should use?

Comment: Which server are you using?  It's possible that not all servers have fully implemented the specification (or implemented it correctly).  I think the intent is that "text" should be a contains match, but the spec itself appears to be a bit ambiguous (as well as grammatically incorrect . . .)

Comment: I'm using the HSPC deployment of Hapi 1.2 at Ex. https://sandbox.hspconsortium.org/dstu2/open-hsp-reference-api/data/Observation?code:text=systolic
I've also tested against the HL7 server:http://fhir2.healthintersections.com.au/open/Observation?code:text=systolic
Which works as long as the string is the start of a word so "sys" works but "tolic" doesn't, which granted doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Also http://fhir2.healthintersections.com.au/open/Observation?code:text=pressure returns no results.

Comment: Hi Amy- I think this is a big in the HAPI server. You are right, we should be at least left matching if not full matching. It looks like we left match for text params, but only complete match for Coding.text params. Will have a look if we can fix this for the upcoming 1.4 release.

Answer (score 0):

The servers seem to do as the spec requests: when using the modifier `:text` on a token search parameter (like `code` here), the spec says:

> ":text The search parameter is processed as a string that searches
>   text associated with the code/value"

If we look at how a server is supposed to search a string, we find:

> "By default, a field matches a string query if the value of the field
>   equals or starts with the supplied parameter value, after both have
>   been normalized by case and accent."

Now, if `code` would have been a true string search parameter, we could have applied the modifier `contains`, however we cannot stack modifiers, so in this case `code:text:containts` would may logical, but is not part of the current specification.

So, I am afraid that there is currently no "standard" way to do what you want.

Comment: If it's a server you control and the implementation supports it, a search parameter could be added directly on code.text.